# Maven aggregate POM version?

Tags: maven, version, pom.xml

What is the point of having a version in a Maven aggregate (multi-module) POM? What is it used for? What would be affected if I change it?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    …
```

Where is the `1.0-SNAPSHOT` used? What artifacts are affected?

On a related note, what semantics does it have? Is it the version of my combined project? Or is it the version solely of the aggregation (which may remain constant through many release versions of the individual modules)?

Comment: Aggregator POM also changes. What if you add a module some day? Version will have to change.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. Where does this version show up? What if I put `12345` as the version? Which artifact would change? Who would ever know without looking inside the aggregate POM? You just added another assertion that the version would "have to change". But why? Explain yourself please.

Comment: The aggregate POM isn't a distributable per se, unless it's also the parent POM of the multi-module project. You handle the versioning as you want, if you want to have a version 12345, nothing is stopping you. It would change something if the aggregate POM is also the parent POM because every module typically share the same version with their aggrate / parent. Otherwise, it's "just" a version that serves as unique identifier of changes made to the aggregate POM itself.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So of what use is it? You say it serves as a "unique identifier". But how would I even know that unique identifier without opening up the file in a text editor? Does it show up anywhere else?

Comment: Not really, it shows up in SCM, but that's it. You could even not change the version at all, keep a `1.0-SNAPSHOT` and forget about it completely. Point is, it's just a helper POM that serves to aggregate the build of other modules, but it doesn't really do more. It isn't released.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm wondering then if I should just use `0.0.0-SNAPSHOT` as the version of the aggregate POM, so as not to confuse this version with the version of any of the modules. Since it doesn't show up in any artifact, `0.0.0-SNAPSHOT` would help to indicate that it's not really the version of anything.